# add image and data frame into a single html body of email

Tags: python, html, email

trying to embed **both** a dataframe and image together in the body of the email. I was able to adapt the folowing code from [email.examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html) to embed the image successfully:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import smtplib

from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.headerregistry import Address
from email.utils import make_msgid

# Create the base text message.
msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = "Ayons asperges pour le déjeuner"
msg['From'] = Address("Pepé Le Pew", "pepe", "example.com")
msg['To'] = (Address("Penelope Pussycat", "penelope", "example.com"),
             Address("Fabrette Pussycat", "fabrette", "example.com"))
msg.set_content("""\
Salut!

Cela ressemble à un excellent recipie[1] déjeuner.

[1] http://www.yummly.com/recipe/Roasted-Asparagus-Epicurious-203718

--Pepé
""")

# Add the html version.  This converts the message into a multipart/alternative
# container, with the original text message as the first part and the new html
# message as the second part.
asparagus_cid = make_msgid()
msg.add_alternative("""\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>Salut!</p>
    <p>Cela ressemble à un excellent
        <a href="http://www.yummly.com/recipe/Roasted-Asparagus-Epicurious-203718">
            recipie
        </a> déjeuner.
    </p>
    <img src="cid:{asparagus_cid}" />
  </body>
</html>
""".format(asparagus_cid=asparagus_cid[1:-1]), subtype='html')
# note that we needed to peel the <> off the msgid for use in the html.

# Now add the related image to the html part.
with open("roasted-asparagus.jpg", 'rb') as img:
    msg.get_payload()[1].add_related(img.read(), 'image', 'jpeg',
                                     cid=asparagus_cid)

# Make a local copy of what we are going to send.
with open('outgoing.msg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(bytes(msg))

# Send the message via local SMTP server.
with smtplib.SMTP('localhost') as s:
    s.send_message(msg)
```

However, not sure how to add a dataframe in addition.  I tried [a couple of functions below](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html) which i believe replacing the old `MIMEMultipart` legacy class:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'A':   [419,382, 382, 382, 411, 411, 411],
         'B':[2,2,3,3,3,3,6],
         'C': np.random.randn(7)*10,
         'D': list('abcdefg')
         }
     )
msg.add_alternative(df.to_html())
#msg.get_payload()[1].add_alternative(df.to_html())
#msg.add_attachment(df.to_html())
#msg.get_payload()[1].add_attachment(df.to_html())
```

but getting `contentmanager` `KeyError`. Also, my `html.format()` statement is already occupied by image processing, so i cannot use `.format(df.to_html())` there, can I?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding your dataframe using variable substitutions, just like you did for your image :

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'A':   [419,382, 382, 382, 411, 411, 411],
         'B':[2,2,3,3,3,3,6],
         'C': np.random.randn(7)*10,
         'D': list('abcdefg')
         }
     )

msg.add_alternative("""\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>Salut!</p>
    <p>Cela ressemble à un excellent
        <a href="http://www.yummly.com/recipe/Roasted-Asparagus-Epicurious-203718">
            recipie
        </a> déjeuner.
    </p>
    <img src="cid:{asparagus_cid}" />
    {dataframe_table}
  </body>
</html>
""".format(asparagus_cid=asparagus_cid[1:-1], dataframe_table=df.to_html()), subtype='html')
```